# How to change one pixel with script

Tags: javascript, vbscript

I want to change color of a pixel in web page.
I will use JavaScript or vbscript.

I tried making a table with 1x1 size cells and color them, but it was very slow.
I need a faster way.

What is the lowest-cost way to color a pixel?

Comment: Can you show your current code?

Comment: You can try the `<canvas>` element.

Comment: Just use a `div` with `position:absolute`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#mycss {
            position: fixed; 
            left: {X}px;   // x coordinate
            top: {Y}px;    // y coordinate
            width: 1px; 
            height: 1px; 
            background-color: black;  // your color
        }
```

Just put the id of the table you created as "mycss"

In Javascript

```
document.getElementById("<your-element-id>").style.position = absolute;
document.getElementById("<your-element-id>").style.left = [<your-pixel-x-coordinate>]px;
document.getElementById("<your-element-id>").style.top= [<your-pixel-y-coordinate>]px;
document.getElementById("<your-element-id>").style.width = 1px;
document.getElementById("<your-element-id>").style.height = 1px;
document.getElementById("<your-element-id>").style.background-color = <your-bg-color>;
```

Comment: -1 because I doubt that just dumping some code without any explanation at all will be any help at all for OP.

Comment: This won't always work if you have other elements being moved around.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go...

**CSS**

```
#myDot {
    position:fixed; /* always stays there even when other elements change */
    width:1px; /* change if you need a bigger dot */
    height:1px; /* change if you need a bigger dot */
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="myDot"></div> <!-- Can be span also -->
```

**JS**

```
document.getElementById("myDot").style.left = 100; // x position
document.getElementById("myDot").style.top = 100; // y position
document.getElementById("myDot").style.background = "red"; // color
```

Answer (score 0):

I seems to me like you want to procedurally create a pixel-based graphic. In that case, the new [HTML5 Canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas) could be what you are searching for. It's an image-like HTML element which you can paint on by drawing lines, shapes, other images, text and much more using javascript.

Comment: I suggest you tu read this article : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas

Comment: @Hugeen unfortunately getImageData and setImageData are very slow, because they pass the image data by value between javascript engine and video buffer. Whenever possible, the high-level graphic functions should be used, because most browsers implement them in hardware. ImageData is usually only needed when you have to do some RGB-based operation (which can't be substituted by alpha blending).

Comment: Anyway: how often do you draw individual pixels in a real-world application? Usually every pixel you draw is part of a sprite or a geometrical shape, and for those there are high-level functions. Pixel-based manipluation could be intersting for custom graphic effects, but in that case I would recommend to use WebGL and do it in hardware by using pixel shaders.